# How set ansible function to when modeule?

Tags: ansible

I want install one of Filebit prospectors only if service redis is running on the host. For that i create default list of prospectors ( redis, aerospike, postgress ) with {{ item.id }}. But right now i want put some expression to "when:" which will install prospector for redis only if it running - how can i do it ?

```
- name: Configure Filebeat prospectors
  template: src=filebeat_conf.yml.j2 dest=/etc/filebeat/conf.d/{{ item.id }}.yml
  notify: restart filebeat
  with_items: prospectors
  when: { " service: " }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use declarative language to configure something based on a temporary state (Redis running or not)?

Comment: I dk now to do it correctly - if you can suggest how to do it - please do.

Comment: It's not a problem **how** to do it correctly, but **what** to do and **why**?

Comment: i want install only one config to server - depends of what service running on it - for example aerospike.
And for that i suppose to use when functions - if service running - that install config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your task in two: collect facts, act depending on facts.
In your case, you can list installed services first, then configure only existing ones.

For example:

```
- hosts: test-host
  vars:
    services:
      - name: apache2
        id: 1
      - name: nginx
        id: 2
      - name: openvpn
        id: 3
  tasks:
    - name: get list of services
      shell: "service --status-all 2>&1 | awk {'print $4'}"
      args:
        warn: false
      register: services_list

    - name: process only existing services
      debug: msg="service {{ item.name }} with id={{ item.id }} exists"
      with_items: "{{ services }}"
      when: item.name in services_list.stdout_lines
```